# ClassNotFoundException in RMI Java

Tags: java, rmi

I can't make compilator finds the class I want Exactly this:
`ctx.rebind("MyInterfaceImplementacja", ref);`. I Could you please correct me?

```
package Pakiet;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface MyInterface extends Remote {
public String echo(String napis) throws RemoteException;
public int dodaj(int wrt1, int wrt2) throws RemoteException;
}
```

---

```
package Pakiet;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;

public class MyInterfaceImplementacja extends PortableRemoteObject implements MyInterface {
  protected MyInterfaceImplementacja() throws RemoteException {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public String echo(String napis) throws RemoteException {
    return "echo" + napis;
  }

  @Override
  public int dodaj(int wrt1, int wrt2) throws RemoteException {
    return wrt1 + wrt2;
  }
}
```

---

```
public class MyInterfaceSerwer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
      MyInterfaceImplementacja ref = new MyInterfaceImplementacja();
      Context ctx = new InitialContext();
      ctx.rebind("MyInterfaceImplementacja", ref);      
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }
}
```

Comment: This is almost the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10648026/509303) you have asked a few minutes later or earlier. Wait for the answers instead of spamming questions.

Comment: Are you getting a compilation error or a runtime exception?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

1. Extend the Implementation class to UnicastRemoteObject instead of PortableRemoteObject.
2. use rmi in your rebind method like this

   ctx.rebind("rmi:MyInterfaceImplementacja", ref);

Keep this below guidelines for future use

down vote

If you are trying to implement the RMI. Please follow these steps
Try this....
 On Server Side:

1. Create Interface which extends java.rmi.Remote interface // shared by client and server
2. Create Implementation class of the Interface, and also extend it to UnicastRemoteObject
3. Now create the Server class which has the rebind method.

   On Client Side:
4. Create Interface which extends java.rmi.Remote interface // shared by client and server
5. Create the Client class which has the lookup method.

   eg:
     On SERVER

   Car.java  // Interface

   CarImpl.java // Implementation Class

   CarServer.java // Server Class

   On CLIENT

   Car.java  // Interface

   CarClient.java  // Client Class

Comment: -1. How will any of this solve this problem? Why does he have to do (1)? How is (2) different from what he has written? How is your 2nd (1) different from what he has written? How is your second (1) different from (4)?

Comment: I think you missed the lines which i wrote in between. The First 1st and 2nd point suggest what he needs to do... and the later 1st to 5th points are for his future reference.. Moreover as he has not mention rmi:MyInterfaceImplementacja, which creates problems during the lookup. I once again urge you to please read the full solution carefully in future before commenting over it.

Comment: I missed nothing, and you have answered nothing. You hardly wrote anything 'in between',and nothing that answers any of my questions. He doesn't have to switch to UnicastRemoteObject to solve this problem; he has already done several of the other steps; much of your advice is merely repetitive; and, again, how will any of this solve the actual problem? What *is* the actual problem that you think all this solves?

Comment: Another baseless claim. From which of your seven points did he get his answer, and why? And when are you planning on answering any of the seven question I have asked you?